# How to run method at set time?

Tags: java, timer

Right now, I'm working on a project, and my setup is something like this: I have a class (`Foo`) which has several methods inside of it which must be activated at different times by the main class.

I've been researching this for quite a while, and the only thing I can find is the `Timer` class, which doesn't quite work, as it can seemingly only time a class, and I don't want 25 different classes for such a basic program.

How do I activate each method in `Foo` individually?

Comment: If I understand correctly you just want to schedule each method separatly ? Something like `MyMethodTimer.call(foo.methodA).in5Minutes(); MyMethodTimer.call(foo.methodB).in15Minutes();` *(not working code !)* ? If that is the case I'm afraid this is going to be more complicated than it looks. And that's in no way a good design, as small as your program might be.

Comment: So if that's the case, would it be more efficient to just trigger a time check after an event that occurs regularly fires?

Comment: You mean, like a big `if()` construct into a `TimerTask` performing a time check and calling the appropriate method at a given time ?

Comment: Exactly. The only problem is, the purpose is to have a different method run each day. There'd be no way to determine whether or not the method for that day has run yet. Would it work to create an external text file which stores the variable, or is there a better way?

Comment: As you are running daily task I'd suggest you use some kind of persistent storage such as a text file anyway. Does your program really need to keep running all the time when it's just executing a task once a day ? I'd suggest you should instead use your OS task scheduler facility (`cron` or Windows scheduled tasks) to run your program once a day and choose a task to run depending on the content of your text file/persistent storage content.

Comment: That being said, I must confess Tony's answer is a perfect match to your question's title "How to run method at set time?", albeit a bit off context regarding your actual need.

Answer (score 1):

The following class works using an extension of `TimerTask` (`MethodTimerTask`) which take in input the `Foo` instance and the method name to call.

In this way, using reflection, the different methods can be called at different times with only one extended `TimerTask` class.

```
public class MyTimerTaskExample {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        timer.schedule(new MethodTimerTask(foo, "method1"), 1000);
        timer.schedule(new MethodTimerTask(foo, "method2"), 3000);
    }

    public static class MethodTimerTask extends TimerTask {

        private String methodName;
        private Foo fooInstance;
        private Exception exception;

        public MethodTimerTask(Foo fooInstance, String methodName) {
            this.methodName = methodName;
            this.fooInstance = fooInstance;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Foo.class.getMethod(methodName).invoke(fooInstance);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                this.exception = e;
            }
        }

        public Exception getException() {
            return exception;
        }

        public boolean hasException() {
            return this.exception != null;
        }

    }

    public static class Foo {

        public void method1() {
            System.out.println("method1 executed");
        }

        public void method2() {
            System.out.println("method2 executed");
        }

    }

}
```

Bonus: the method `getException()` returns the eventual Exception catched while executing `methodName` of `Foo`.